# Using a vgroup as a drop target in Flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex-spark

Is it possible to use a VGroup as a drop target in flex?  I like the functionality of a vgroup (adding elements easily, etc) but I haven't found a way to get it to register when things are dropped on it.

Is this possible?

Comment: The drag Events are defined in the UIComponent which the VGroup extends.  What happens if you listen to the dragDrop and/or dragEnter events on the VGroup?  If the events fire, then that is your answer.

Comment: Listening manually was being difficult (and doesn't have dragDrop or dragEnter), but I found a workaround which was actually better, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in my case was to surround the whole thing in a VBox, which does support dragEnter and dragDrop, which makes configuration easier.

```
    <s:Group top="30" width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:VBox id="dropTargetVBox" label="if" 
                width="100%" height="100%"
                borderStyle="none" dragEnter="dragEnterHandler(event)" dragDrop="dragDropHandler(event)">
            <s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%">
                <s:VGroup id="lst" gap="0" height="100%" width="100%">
                </s:VGroup>
            </s:Scroller>
        </mx:VBox>
    </s:Group>
```

And on top of this, also allows me to put other things inside (which is desirable for what I'm trying to do).